# I am considering a visit to a Nevada brothel. What should I say at the US border?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, sex, nevada

I am a Canadian citizen/resident. I am considering a drive to a northern Nevada city to visit one of its legal brothels. According to my research, international sex tourism is legal as long as no minors are involved (though I would very much appreciate being told as much if it is not). Even so, I fear that I may be denied entry if I am completely honest about my purpose. Inventing a second purpose for my trip will be difficult, as I am not interested in any attractions along the way.

Comment: Presumably you do not need a visa when [visiting "for purposes of pleasure"](https://www.legalline.ca/legal-answers/do-canadians-need-a-visa-to-visit-the-usa/). So if asked, the reason for the visit is "pleasure".

Comment: I’d imagine if they denied entry to everyone with the same purpose, the place would be half-empty :-)

Comment: While the regulations talk about visits for "business or pleasure", you'll probably get less funny looks from the immigration officer if you say you're visiting for "tourism".

Comment: ..which is true. Since you are taking a road trip to Nevada, you are a [tourist](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/tourist). Regarding the legality, please read [Prostitution in Nevada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prostitution_in_Nevada).

Comment: If there ever was a question that deserved the late lamented [tag:all-adults-here] tag ...

Comment: Suppose you were planning to visit the grand canyon or a museum.  You could reasonably tell the officer that the purpose of your visit is just tourism rather than environmental tourism or art tourism.

Answer (score 11):

First, let's review the typical roster of questions to anyone -- the iron rule is to never lie and never offer information unasked:

> Why are you visiting the United States?

I wanted to see Nevada. (This is enough.)

> Where will you be staying?

If you have a hotel reservation, bring it printed.

> Who will you be visiting?

You aren't planning to see anyone in particular.

> How long will you be staying?

Name it.

> How much money are you bringing?

Same. These days this is becoming rare with credit cards.

> Have you visited the United States before, and if so, did you remain longer than you were supposed to?
>
> How often do you come to the United States?

Just answer short and truthfully.

At the end of the day, though, you are Canadian. The scrutiny will be absolutely minimal. Noone will press questions, they couldn't care less. (Source: first hand experience of the scrutiny as a resident travelling on a Hungarian passport then the sudden evaporation of grilling the moment I started using a Canadian passport.)

Answer (score 6):

As you say, you intend to engage in 100% legal behavior, and, as others have commented, you are entering the USA as a tourist. If they ask, tell them  the truth about where you are going, but don't bring up unnecessary facts or use charged language. For example:

> Officer: Why are you coming in to the US?
>
> You: For tourism.
>
> Officer: How long will you be here?
>
> You: About a week, maybe two.
>
> Officer: Do you have a specific destination?
>
> You: Yeah, I plan to visit the Starlight Bunny Resort in Nevada.
>
> Officer: Do you have any drugs or guns?
>
> You: No.
>
> Officer: Have a great trip!